# WCF-RIA Services Client OutputCache - not working in IE with localhost

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

We are using the WCF-RIA Services in our project. 
On part is a search which will trigger a RIA request on the server.

For this request we have enabled the Client output cache using this attribute:

```
[OutputCache(OutputCacheLocation.Client, duration: 2 * 60)]
```

We want to use the client cache, because the information to be cached are user specific. The problem ist, that the cache works fine in Firefox and IE after the application is installed in an IIS, but while debugging IE seems to ignore the caching.

Maybe this is not really a RIA Service specific problem but more of an IE problem. It looks as IE sees "Hey, this is a request to localhost, I don't want to cache that" (some kind of feature).

This is a bit unhelpful, because the debugging situation is not the same as the "live" situation.

Is there a way to use the WCF-RIA Services client cache in IE while debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to test this using either your machine name in the URL or using localhost. (note the dot at the end) instead of localhost. [See here for more info](http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2008/01/10/tip-for-using-fiddler-on-localhost.aspx).

Once you have it working with Fiddler you should be able to see if your caching is on or off and debug it.

Comment: Yes, I have already confirmed the behavior using fiddler. While debugging localhost, the cache is not used. If the application is installed, the cache is used.